# Regular expression multiline validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, multiline

In my ASP.NET Web Form I have a multiline `TextBox` which should be validated with RegularExpression Validator. Text box should contain one or more strings "a" (just 'a' char, nothing else).

So far I got these regular expressions for my `RegularExpressionValidator` object:

```
(?m:(^a$)+)
(?m:\A(^a$)+\Z)
(?m:^a$)
```

and some others. Neither works. Guess there is something fundamental I'm not getting yet.

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?

Here's the code involved.

A Button (just for postbacks):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

The TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the regex validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
    ValidationExpression="(?m:(^a$)+)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

There is nothing else on that Web Form. I've only added those controls and modified properties. I've even did all this using VS GUI.

---

Using CustomValidator and doing `Regex.Match(TextBox1, @"(?m:(^a$)+)")` in it works just fine. Something is wrong with RegularExpressionValidator I guess.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of valid strings? Each line can contain multiple 'a' characters or just one single 'a' character?

Comment: Hey Marco! It's just one single 'a' character, that's for simplicity. But actually it's not the point. It could be any expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match multiple lines, don't forget to also match the line terminators; they are not implied in `$`.

```
(?m:(^a$\r?\n?)+)
```

might work better.

This matches

```
a
```

or

```
a
a
a
```

etc.

And, since you're asking for a tutorial, how about [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)?

Comment: Thanks Tim, but it doesn't work. (?m:(^a\r?\n?$)+) this one doesn't work either. But (?m:(^a\r?\n?)+) does. There is something else about $ :)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Done that. But I'll go look through it again, in case I missed the answer for my question.

Comment: The last regex you wrote in your comment is exactly the same one in my answer. What do you mean?

Comment: No, it's not. There is no $ sign.

Comment: Oh, right. But that shouldn't matter. I've just tested my regex, and it works as advertised. Perhaps you should update your question with the actual code you're using - the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Strange. It does match on regexlib.com, but not in my app. There is nothing but this textbox and validator object. And I'm just putting this regex into ValidationExpression field.

Comment: And you're sure you don't have any additional whitespace anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Just in case I've just checked.

Comment: OK, the Regex is obviously correct, checked with RegexBuddy, Python, and regexlib. So the error is elsewhere. I don't know the validator object and can't help you further with that.

Comment: Found the problem: Unescaped backslashes.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't worked. And again (?m:(^a\r?\n?)+) does work, so I don't think that those backslashes are unescaped.

Comment: Doing regex match using Regex.Match(TextBox1, @"(?m:(^a$\r?\n?)+)") in CustomValidator object everything works just fine. Something is wrong with RegularExpressionValidator I guess.